# Why can't I update this mutable Map's value for this key in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have a function that I need to update a mutable Map by decrementing the value associated with a key passed into the function. It looks like this:

```
def selectProduct(product: String, insertedAmount: Float): (String,String) = {
    val price = products(product)
    val returnedProduct = if (insertedAmount >= price) product else ""
    if (returnedProduct != "") {
      inventory.update(product, inventory(product) - 1)
    }
    val message = display.displayMessage(product, returnedProduct)
    (returnedProduct, message)
}
```

where inventory is defined like this:

```
def inventory = mutable.Map[String, Int](
  product1 -> 3,
  product2 -> 3,
  product3 -> 3
)
```

I have tests set up to check that after the item is selected in selectProduct, the inventory should have one fewer of that item. This test fails. I have verified the item is selected correctly. I have tried declaring the inventory value with both def and val. I have tried doing this in the REPL, and what I am trying to do works just fine. Why won't this value update?

Update: Test Code

```
class VendingMachineSpec extends UnitSpec {

def vendingMachine = new VendingMachine()

it should "remove a purchased item from the inventory" in {
  val sixtyFiveCents = vendingMachine.coinOp.insertCoin(QUARTER, vendingMachine.coinOp.insertCoin(QUARTER, vendingMachine.coinOp.insertCoin(NICKEL, vendingMachine.coinOp.insertCoin(DIME, Coins.coins(PENNY)))))
  assert(sixtyFiveCents == SIXTY_FIVE_CENTS)

  val results = vendingMachine.selectProduct(product1, sixtyFiveCents)
  val product = results._1
  val message = results._2
  assert(product == product1)
  assert(message == "Thank you!")

  assert(vendingMachine.inventory(product1) == 2)
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your test code?

Comment: What happens if you print the adjusted entry just after adjusting it, or run this in a debugger and examine the value? That would help work out where the problem really is. For instance, what if you've accidentally set the price of product1 to more than 65 cents?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Printing that value out shows the value associated with the product1 key is always 2. I have several tests around this function, and the value is always 2.

Comment: I meant that value is always 2 when I print it out inside the if statement in the selectProduct function

Comment: If it';s OK in the function, but wrong outside, then you're not looking at the same object,

Comment: Okay, I tried calling the selectProduct method twice in the same test, and that prints out 2 both times. Is it getting reset? FYI, this is with the definition of inventory changed to using val instead of def

Comment: Can you please update to a [mcve]? The details may matter.

Comment: is `vendingMachine` still a `def`? In which case you're getting a new one of those each time you reference `vendingMachine` too. Which would also explain your issue.

Comment: Yeah, it is. That's gotta be the problem. I'll check it out after work. Could you add this as an answer? I can accept it later when i test it out

Comment: I think @irundaia should get the credit as his or her answer spotted the def/var issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies with the definition of the `inventory`. You've defined the `inventory` as:

```
def inventory = mutable.Map[String, Int](???)
```

By defining it as a `def`, you've made sure that the inventory is reevealuated whenever it's used. So suppose you have:

```
val x = inventory
val y = inventory
```

both `x` and `y` would be pointing to different objects.

For your code to work, you'd have to replace the definition of inventory with either

```
val inventory = mutable.Map[String, Int](???)
```

or

```
lazy val inventory = mutable.Map[String, Int](???)
```

Comment: I already tried using val and I got the same result in the tests.

Comment: The problem was with my VendingMachine definition in my test. Thanks for bringing up def vs val